# Explicit construction of entity type ### in query is not allowed

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce-3.5

I use a Windows phone 8, MVVM + SQL Server CE 3.5 database

In folder `model` I have a declaration of table `<TblCollections>`

In folder `ViewModel` have this code for getting the collection.

```
public IEnumerable<TblCollections> GetTblCollections()
{
        using (DbContext db = new DbContext(DbContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            var query = from collection in db.TblCollections
                        select new TblCollections
                        {
                            a = (string)collection.a,
                            b = (int)collection.b,
                            id = (int)collection.id,
                        };

            IEnumerable<TblCollections> _TblCollections = query.ToList();

            return _TblCollections;
        }
    }
```

I receive error on `query.ToList();`

> Explicit construction of entity type "TblCollections" in query is not allowed

Why?

Comment: What's the issue in using 'from collection in db.TblCollections
select collection'

Comment: I need to use it in this way because I make count in the select new. for example select new TblCollections
                        {
                            a = (string)collection.a,
                            b = (int)collection.b,
                            id = (int)collection.id, count= (int)collection.tblfiles.count();
                        };

Comment: try below anonymous class suggestion as you want few properties that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify class and Try this(Untested code):

```
IEnumerable<TblCollections> query = from collection in db.TblCollections
                        select new
                        {
                            a = (string)collection.a,
                            b = (int)collection.b,
                            id = (int)collection.id,
                        };
```